# What fraction of biomass is cultivated by humans? Have we increased the number of large animals?

Tags: zoology, agriculture

What fraction of "large animals" are domesticated by humans, compared to those who are wild? I mean cows, pigs, sheep, horses, dogs, cats in relation to comparable wild animals. Different measurements to a similar effect would also be of interest. Possibly including even chicken and fisheries.

I wonder if there are more "large animals" alive on Earth today than thousands of years ago when human agriculture was much smaller?

I'd also be interested in some measurement of how large a fraction of vegetable life on Earth consists of our agricultural cereals et cetera.

Comment: XKCD did a bit of research on this, though it doesn't handle historic data, and only mammals: http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1338:_Land_Mammals

Comment: @Deruijter That's... amazing! I suspected it would be large, but this is a factor of ten bigger again than I expected. If correct, I suppose that the mass of wild land mammals cannot have decreased nearly as much as human and domesticated land mammals have increased. Is the age of industrialization at the same time the age of the land mammals?

Comment: The loss of wild large animals may be worse than you think. In the 1800s, settlers moving west across america described gigantic herds of buffalo, which are all gone now. Their mass has probably been replaced by cattle. One important factor is probably man made fertilizer through the haber process to capture nitrogen from the air and make ammonia. We have more than doubled the mass of bioavailable nitrogen in the last century, allowing us to grow a lot more grain to feed to cattle, pigs, and chickens. The nitrogen also causes algal blooms and dead zones.